# condition variable doesn't wake after notify

Tags: c++

I have a main thread waiting on a condition variable, and a worker thread that notifies it. Here's a simple example of what happens.

```
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex mt;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool flag = false;

void worker() {
  std::unique_lock lock(mt);
  std::cout << "Worker started.\n";
  flag = true;
  lock.release();
  cv.notify_one();
  std::cout << "Worker done.\n";
}

int main() {
  std::thread thread(worker);
  std::unique_lock lock(mt);
  std::cout << "Main waiting.\n";
  cv.wait(lock, [](){ std::cout << "Main checking: " << flag << '\n'; return flag; });
  std::cout << "Main done.\n";
  thread.join();
}
```

What I thought would happen was one of these things:

1. The main thread acquires the lock first, and waits for the worker thread to finish.
2. The worker thread acquires the lock first, finishes, and main doesn't wait.

What happens in practice is that `main` never wakes up.

> Main waiting.
>
> Main checking: 0
>
> Worker started.
>
> Worker done.

And then it hangs.

Comment: The reason why the program doesn't work is because `release()` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Tactical note: Rather than trying to manually unlock the mutex, change the scope on the `unique_lock` with an extra set of braces to automatically unlock where you want it unlocked. `{std::unique_lock lock(mt); do_critical_stuff(); } do_regular_stuff();`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ahh thank you, with an example this small I knew I had to be making a dumb mistake somewhere. That fixed it, if you want to make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lock.release();
```

`release`() did not do what you thought it would do, unlock the mutex. That would be `lock.unlock()`. `release()` disconnects the `std::unique_lock` from its mutex, but leaves the mutex in a locked state.